# jQuery data rendering issue

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I'm trying to render a menu containing check boxes something using JQuery according to a defined template in a div. I have a search box which will narrow down the menu.

There is something strange happening. When I have huge list of menu items (around 5000 items), it renders fine initially. Then if I type something and narrow down the result, it works fine. But when I press backspace and go back to the full list of items, the div gets displaced for a second and  reappears in the correct position.

I have no clue of whats happening. Any pointers on where to look to debug will be helpful. Thanks!

Comment: Can you add some code or something so we can understand more better way that what you want?

Answer (score 0):

Take a look at the [Chrome Developer Tools](https://developers.google.com/chrome-developer-tools/). There's a ton of things in there you'll probably never use, but for this task I'd have a look at the elements tab and also the scripts tab to pause JavaScript events and inspect the DOM elements' styles.

This is a generic answer to a generic question though. If you're using Firefox, check out [Firebug](https://addons.mozilla.org/en-US/firefox/addon/firebug/), but I prefer Chrome's tools and find them better integrated and user friendly, mostly from having used them a lot more.